# When running my first flutter app using the android studio emulator, I get an error regarding dependencies

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

after hours of sitting and installing flutter and more related things so I can run a flutter app, I successfully ran the DEMO incrementor app on the anroid emulator.

now when trying to run another project, I get this error:

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:devDebugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not create task ':app:generateDevDebugLintModel'.
> Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because "value" is null

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2,935ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

For anyone asking, I did make sure to download the Android SDK Tool for this android device.
I also made sure to download everything that I was asked for, so now the flutter doctor responds that I have everything set up regarding flutter.

I also manually downloaded Gradle and made sure to edit the path.

for you might ask,this is my build.gradle file dependencies inside of android\app:

`dependencies {     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"     implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0")     implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx" }`

and this is my build.gradle file dependencies inside of android only:

`dependencies {         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'     }`

if anyone can help, please do!

I am expecting the app to succesfully run on the anroid emulator.
and note: it does run successfully on the browser.

Answer (score 5):

I think I encountered the same thing - and the tough part was that it had nothing to do with Lints at all, which threw me off. Here's what happened. I was getting that same error with a project I was working on, but was able to run the example project. Going between the two projects comparing files, I started commenting things out and figured out I was missing a key in `local.properties` that was being loaded into my `android/app/build.gradle` file. In my case, it was the apiKey for google maps.

That `build.gradle` file had the following:

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig{
       ...
       manifestPlaceholders = [mapsApiKey: localProperties['mapsApiKey']]
   }
   ...
}
```

When there wasn't actually a `mapsApiKey` in the `local.properties` file. Hence the `"value" is null` I think.

So adding `mapsApiKey=` to that file fixed this for me. Are you missing any definitions like that anywhere?

Comment: omg... After hours of searching through cryptic exception logs. You saved my day, thanks!

Comment: @Jeff_Beyer Thanks! Saved me hours of trial and error.